# Query EmailTemplate and BrandTemplate

Tags: soql

I'm attempting to get the BrandTemplate along with the EmailTemplate in a single statement, I have this soql query

```
SELECT ID, Name,BrandTemplate.Value FROM EmailTemplate
```

Error message:

> doesn't understand relationship BrandTemplate.

Comment: You're going to need a second query.

Comment: Nick - Adrian is right; you should self answer this with the two queries